# Homebrew get list of formulas in a tap

Tags: homebrew

How would I (through the command line) get the list of formulas in a tap from homebrew.
Running brew tap only list the tap but not the formulas that exist as part of that tap.

If such a command doesn't exist, how can I programmatically retrieve the list of formulas.

Answer (score 18):

The list of formulas in a tap is exposed in `brew tap-info $TAP --json`.

From here, you can use a JSON command line parser to extract the list, such as [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq):

For example, to list all the formulas from homebrew/cask-fonts and kde-mac/kde:

```
brew tap-info homebrew/cask-fonts kde-mac/kde --json | jq -r '.[]|(.formula_names[],.cask_tokens[])'
```

Comment: Excellent solution! Thanks! +1!

Comment: I'm wondering why something similar is not implemented as a command by the official brew team. We could suggest that to them. Something like `brew tap-info --list-formulas $TAP`, perhaps.

Comment: @rmbianchi you can always submit a pull request! When I was looking into this myself, I had to add `cask_files` to the json output, which was accepted as a PR, and then a maintainer added the `cask_tokens` based on that.

Comment: Just added `function brew-tap-formulas { brew tap-info --json "$@" | jq -r '.[]|(.formula_names[],.cask_tokens[])' | sort -V }` to my `~/.profile'.

Answer (score 10):

After tapping:

```
TAP=telemachus/homebrew-desc  # (or whatever; need the homebrew- prefix)
TAP_PREFIX=$(brew --prefix)/Library/Taps
ls $TAP_PREFIX/$TAP/Formula/*.rb || ls $TAP_PREFIX/$TAP/*.rb
```

Answer (score 4):

An update to [Tim Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/892260/tim-smith)'s answer that includes the necessary (for me) `Homebrew/` directory in the `TAP_PREFIX` path:

```
TAP=telemachus/homebrew-desc  # (or whatever; need the homebrew- prefix)
TAP_PREFIX=$(brew --prefix)/Homebrew/Library/Taps
ls $TAP_PREFIX/$TAP/Formula/*.rb 2>/dev/null || ls $TAP_PREFIX/$TAP/*.rb 2>/dev/null | xargs -I{} basename {} .rb
```

I also added redirecting stderr to /dev/null, and stripping out all but the formula's proper name in the last line.

Answer (score 2):

Adapted from @cstork comment on @forivall answer....

1. Make sure you have `jq` installed:

```
brew install jq
```

2. Add the following function to your `.zshrc` or equivalent (like `.bashrc`)

```
# Lists formulas from a given brew tap
# Call it with one or more taps to see their formulas
#   e.g.: brew-list-formulas tap/tap othertap/othertap
# Call it with no tap to list all taps
#   e.g.: brew-list-formulas
# Modified from https://stackoverflow.com/a/60607145/172272
function brew-list-formulas
{
  if (( $# == 0 )) then
    echo "Please specify one or more taps whose formulas you want listed.";
    echo "  e.g.: brew-list-formulas tap/tap othertap/othertap";
    echo "";
    echo "Available taps are:";
    echo "";
    brew tap;
  else
    echo "Formulas for tap(s) $* are:"
    echo "";
    brew tap-info --json "$@" | jq -r '.[]|(.formula_names[],.cask_tokens[])' | sort -V;
  fi
}
```

3. Source your `.zshrc` (or equivalent)

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

4. Use it!

```
> brew-list-formulas

Please specify one or more taps whose formulas you want listed.
  e.g.: brew-list-formulas tap/tap othertap/othertap

Available taps are:

clojure/tools
homebrew/cask
homebrew/cask-fonts
homebrew/core

> brew-list-formulas clojure/tools

Formulas for tap(s) clojure/tools are:

clojure/tools/clojure
clojure/tools/clojure@1.10.1.510
clojure/tools/clojure@1.10.1.524
clojure/tools/clojure@1.10.1.528
```

Answer (score 0):

As syntax changed recently, then use now the following commands

```
export TAP=cloudfoundry/homebrew-tap
export TAP_PREFIX=$(brew --prefix)/Homebrew/Library/Taps
ls $TAP_PREFIX/$TAP/Formula/*.rb || ls $TAP_PREFIX/$TAP/*.rb
zsh: no matches found: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/cloudfoundry/homebrew-tap/Formula/*.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/cloudfoundry/homebrew-tap/bbl.rb         /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/cloudfoundry/homebrew-tap/cf-cli@6.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/cloudfoundry/homebrew-tap/bbr.rb         /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/cloudfoundry/homebrew-tap/cf-cli@7.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/cloudfoundry/homebrew-tap/bosh-cli.rb    /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/cloudfoundry/homebrew-tap/credhub-cli.rb
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/cloudfoundry/homebrew-tap/cf-cli.rb      /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/cloudfoundry/homebrew-tap/uaa-cli.rb
```