# Homebrew get a list of installed formulae by tap

Tags: homebrew

Perhaps following a little on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25334787/homebrew-get-list-of-formulas-in-a-tap) I would like to know if is it possible to get a list of installed formulas with Homebrew by tap. I would like to untap a repository, but I would like first to check the formulas I've installed with it.

Is this in anyway possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `brew list --full-name`.

It puts the tap name in front of the formula name for all installed formulas that do not belong to the core tap (`homebrew/core`).